# Valgrind and sigaction for SIGRTMAX

Tags: c++, signals, valgrind

I call `sigaction` to install a handler for `SIGRTMAX`, which is usually fine.  But this fails if I profile the executable with valgrind.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because valgrind reserves one signal, the highest numbered one, for it's own internal use (the scheduler uses it to interrupt a thread that is blocked in a system call) so it rejects any attempt by the client program to install a handler for that signal or otherwise manipulate it.